# How can we use same view in different tabs and at the same time different views change in that tab?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using different Tabs on same page. I want that when i switch the tab the view i want to replace will replace and the view which want to show same in other tab will remain same

Comment: can you please share the code?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Bootstrap Tab panes for this purpose If you want to replace the view with respect to the tab clicked

Here's the code

//These will be your tabs that when clicked will open up the divs with Id given in their **href**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about">About</a></li>     
</ul>
```

//These will be your tab content that basically is the tab content for all the buttons/tabs above

```
<div class="tab-content">
```

// tab content for home

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
```

// tab content for about

```
<div id="about" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Hope this helps